My 03 montero sport hesitates and sometimes will die but only when the weather is cold
2003 mitsubishi montero sport 3.0l hesitates and sometimes will die when the weather is cold. Otherwise it runs fine.somtimes it might happen soon other times it might not happen for an hour or more but only in cold weather.

Right off the bat multiple ideas what is happening. Moisture in the Fuel Lines which freeze and block intake. Ignition issues. Does the car missfire? A clogged Filter or the Fuelpump which is old and weak Maybe the MAF Sensor? Could also be the ECT Sensor. I guess we need more Infos on what you already did to narrow it down
